# Extracting information within a column

Tags: unix, awk, extract, vcf-vcard

I am trying to extract a subset of my data which is tab delimited. I would like to use some information in a column. For example column2 has three scores seperated by ";"

```
col1 col2
1    a=2;b=1.1;c=0    
1    a=0.2;b=0.2;c=0.5  
1    a=1.5;b=1.9;c=3.5
```

I would like to extract the rows whose b value is grater than 1. In this case my desired output will be

```
col1 col2
1    a=2;b=1.1;c=0    
1    a=1.5;b=1.9;c=3.5
```

I tried to use awk but extracting information within the column did not work. Also, the order is not always the same (a,b,c etc.)It would be best to include 'b > 1' in the search criteria. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the order of Column2 can be random, you can do something like:

```
awk -F'\t' '
NR>1 {
    split($2,ary,/[;=]/); 
        for (i=1;i<=length(ary);i++) { 
            if (ary[i]=="b" && ary[i+1]>1) {
                print $0 
            }
        }
    next
}1' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat f
col1    col2
1       a=2;b=1.1;c=0    
1       a=0.2;b=0.2;c=0.5  
1       a=1.5;b=1.9;c=3.5  

$ awk -F'\t' '
NR>1 {
    split($2,ary,/[;=]/); 
        for (i=1;i<=length(ary);i++) { 
            if (ary[i]=="b" && ary[i+1]>1) {
                print $0 
            }
        }
    next
}1' f
col1    col2
1       a=2;b=1.1;c=0    
1       a=1.5;b=1.9;c=3.5
```

Comment: thanks @Jaypal. it is working. But does NR need to be 0 so that it includes the first line as well? i just tried on a different set of data and it misses the first entry. I changed it to 0 and it seem to work fine. What does NR do?

Comment: `NR` stores the line number of file under test. In our case first line is the header. As we don't want to do split on our header and print it as is, the whole action is done on `NR>1`, which essentially means - leave my header line alone and do this on all remaining lines. `1` at the very end will print our header line as is. If you don't have first line as your header in your main file then you can remove it altogether. In that case you can also remove `next` and `1`. They were all added for printing header line.

Comment: You don't need to call `length(ary)` for every field. `Spilt` returns this for you. `n=split($2,a,/;=/); for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`

Answer (score 2):

#### GNU sed

```
sed -r '/b=0.[0-9]?|b=1.0|b=1([^0-9.]|$)/d' file
```

Comment: @user1007742    it finds all lines with `b>1` and display it at the screen. What info do you need?